# How to retrieve xml data from Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract values from an XML document using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415452/how-to-extract-values-from-an-xml-document-using-javascript)

My demo.xml file contain the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user>
<details>
<name>abc</name>
<class>xyz</class>
<city>pqr</city>
</details>
<info>
<id>123</id>
<code>456</code>
</info>
</user>
```

I want to fetch all these data from file demo.xml into my code using Javascript. How can I get this? Any solution? Thanks....

Comment: possiblity duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5415452/668970

Comment: Although you can get the values using the standard DOM interface your browser (should) provide, most of the times it's better and safer to use a framework (like jQuery) to select the elements. Are you using any?

Comment: @Gerardo Lima: No I am not using jQuery for it. I want to use Javascript for this. Can it possible in Javascript or jQuery is better option?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

here is an example wich can put you in the right direction:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "/path/demo.xml", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseXML;
var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("user");
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var names = user.getElementsByTagName("name");
    for(var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        alert(names[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequests aren't always asynchrone; the false in request.open("GET", "/path/demo.xml", false) makes it synchrone

Comment: It returning the object instead of value

Comment: It's working well in Firefox for me,.. but throwing error `Javascript runtime error: Access is denied` in Chrome & IE