# extract XML data from a url with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I would like to extract information from this url Radionomy.

http://radionomy.letoptop.fr/currentsong/get_api.php?radiouid=a2880b1c-2e83-4767-9804-8f3015978a38

I've been doing it with PHP but I consume many resources on the hosting, I'd do it with javascript, is there any way?

PHP:

```
<?php

$xml = @ simplexml_load_file('http://radionomy.letoptop.fr/currentsong/get_api.php?radiouid=a2880b1c-2e83-4767-9804-8f3015978a38');
foreach ($xml as $track){

$artiste = $track->artists;
$titre = $track->title;
}


?>
```

Basically what the PHP code is to extract the title information and cover art of what's playing on the radio at that time.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with JS [Retreive xml from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684145/how-to-retrieve-xml-data-from-javascript)

Comment: You can't do this with JS - [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Specific questions are more likely to get helpful answers. Can you show some of the JavaScript that you've tried so far and where you are running into issues?