# Call JQuery function in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This script is used to call jquery marquee

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('example3').marquee({   
            gap: "0",
            speed: "3000",
            direction: "up",
            duplicated: "true"
        });
    });  
</script>
```

This is working fine for static content in a div

I want to apply the same script for dynamic content which I will fetch from the xml file and add to the div using js.

How do I call this in my js after fetching the content from the xml file.

Comment: you may want to bind the event after the item is loaded.

Comment: check this on how to fetch data from xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684145/how-to-retrieve-xml-data-from-javascript .. In the callback method, you can retreive values from xml and use it your method

Comment: Does <script> tag will be displayed after running the php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a standard function.

```
<script>
    function applyMarquee() {
        $('example3').marquee({
            gap: "0",
            speed: "3000",
            direction: "up",
            duplicated: "true"
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        loadContentFromXml();
        applyMarquee();
    });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.xml",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data){
      $('example3').html(data).marquee({
        gap: "0",
        speed: "3000",
        direction: "up",
        duplicated: "true"
    });
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function functionName(){
    $('example3').marquee({
        gap: "0",
        speed: "3000",
       direction: "up",
       duplicated: "true"
    });
   }
   $(document).ready(function(){
      functionName();
    });   
</script>
```