# Search through an XML file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to build a Japanese study guide. I downloaded a huge Japanese English dictionary file in XML from [here](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/edict_doc.html). It's about 3,000,000 lines of code.

Here is an example entry from the file:

```
<JMdict>
    <entry>
        <ent_seq>1000110</ent_seq>
        <k_ele>
            <keb>ＣＤプレーヤー</keb>
            <ke_pri>spec1</ke_pri>
        </k_ele>
        <k_ele>
            <keb>ＣＤプレイヤー</keb>
        </k_ele>
        <r_ele>
            <reb>シーディープレーヤー</reb>
            <re_restr>ＣＤプレーヤー</re_restr>
            <re_pri>spec1</re_pri>
        </r_ele>
        <r_ele>
            <reb>シーディープレイヤー</reb>
            <re_restr>ＣＤプレイヤー</re_restr>
        </r_ele>
        <sense>
            <pos>&n;</pos>
            <gloss>CD player</gloss>
        </sense>
    </entry>
</JMdict>
```

I'm not too familiar with how to use XML. I want to be able to search through the file and return the entry information. `<keb>` and `<reb>` are going to be the Japanese terms, and inside `<gloss>` is the English meaning. There are multiple `<keb>` and `<reb>` because there are multiple ways to say and spell the same word. If someone could just tell me a simple way to search typing the word in English in an input box and search each `<entry>` for a match in `<gloss>` using regex that would be enough for me to get the project rolling. I just want to type an English word and return the Japanese equivalent.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is very easy with jQuery. You just pass it your XML, it becomes a jQuery object. Something like `var $xml = $(xmldata); $xml.find("ent_seq"); $xml.find("entry").find("re_pri")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to extract values from an XML document using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415452/how-to-extract-values-from-an-xml-document-using-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684145/how-to-retrieve-xml-data-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = document.createElement("div");
xml.innerHTML = "<JMdict><entry><ent_seq>1000110</ent_seq><k_ele><keb>ＣＤプレーヤー</keb><ke_pri>spec1</ke_pri></k_ele><k_ele><keb>ＣＤプレイヤー</keb></k_ele><r_ele><reb>シーディープレーヤー</reb><re_restr>ＣＤプレーヤー</re_restr><re_pri>spec1</re_pri></r_ele><r_ele><reb>シーディープレイヤー</reb><re_restr>ＣＤプレイヤー</re_restr></r_ele><sense><pos>&n;</pos><gloss>CD player</gloss></sense></entry></JMdict>"

//xml.innerHTML = url xml

xml.querySelector("keb").innerText // will give value in first keb
xml.querySelector("reb").innerText // will give you first reb
xml.querySelector("gloss").innerText // will give you gloss

use querySelectorAll("keb")[0/1] to access specific keb.
Or write any query you want like
xml.querySelector("k_ele keb") // keb inside k_ele
xml.querySelector("r_ele re_pri").innerText // returns "spec1"
```